How can I call a setter function inside of setState
I have the following class:
export default class Global {
  public config!: Config;
  public components!: Component[];

  constructor(config: Config) {
    if (!config) {
      throw new Error("Missing global eTech UI config");
    }

    this.config = config;
    this.components = [];
  }

  private deepMerge(target: any, source: any): any {
    for (const key in source) {
      if (source[key] instanceof Object && key in target) {
        Object.assign(source[key], this.deepMerge(target[key], source[key]));
      }
    }

    Object.assign(target || {}, source);
    return target;
  }

  public set setConfig(config: AddConfig) {
    this.config = this.deepMerge(this.config, config);
  }

  public set setComponent(component: AddComponent) {
    let tempComponent: Component = component as Component;

    if (!component.id) {
      tempComponent.id = "UI__" + nanoid();
    } else {
      tempComponent.id = component.id;
    }

    this.components.forEach((component) => {
      if (component.id === tempComponent.id) {
        throw new Error("Two components cannot have the same id");
      }
    });

    this.components.push(tempComponent);
  }

  public getComponentById(id: string) {
    return this.components.find((component) => component.id === id);
  }
}


Which I am passing into state:
const [uiConfig, setUiConfig] = useState<Global>(new Global(config));

My question is how do I call the setter methods inside of setState? Is this best practice to do? Is it even possible? And is so what is the best way of doing this?

If you use React function components, you can have an effect that listens to one state and updates the next (chaining them).

It's not entirely clear to me what you mean, and you may be trying to do something incorrectly in the first place.  Where are you currently attempting to do whatever it is you're trying to do?  What isn't working as expected?

@David In my TypeScript class I have setters. For example setComponent. I want to be able to call setUiConfig({config.setComponent = {theme: {colors: {themeColors: {primary: "red"}}}}}) and have save the new changes to the class.

That setter would have to return a new instance of the object in order for React to perceive it as a state update.  It looks like you may be trying to mix incompatible things here.  This object appears to be intended to internally manage state on its own, not to be a simple DTO of values that React's state would use.
